# How to use distinct in mssql with many tables?

Tags: sql, duplicates, distinct, records

With the below SQL statement I get all information about a student as needed except for one problem which is duplicate records when in fact last entered record for each student needed only.

```
Student ID      Year level   Semester
20012-000001    20012-20013    1
20012-000001    20012-20013    2
20012-000001    20012-20013    3    
20012-000001    20012-20013    4        
20012-000001    20012-20013    5
```

```
    sqlSTR = "SELECT tblStudent.StudentID AS '??? ??????' , (tblStudent.FirstName + ' ' + tblStudent.MiddleName + ' ' + tblStudent.GrandFatherName + ' ' + tblStudent.LastName) as '?????' ," & _
                "tblStudent.Gender as '?????', tblStudent.Citizenship as '???????', tblStudent.Type as '??? ?????'," & _
                "tblDepartment.DepartmentTitle as '?????', tblEnrolment.SchoolYear as '????? ????????',tblYearLevel.YearLevelTitle as '????? ???????',  " & _
                "'????'= CASE WHEN Len(tblGraduate.StudentID)<>12 THEN '???' ELSE ''End , " & _
                "'???? ???'= CASE WHEN Len(tblDropped.StudentID)<>12 THEN '???' ELSE ''End , " & _
                "'??????'= CASE WHEN tblStudent.Transferee ='True' THEN '???' ELSE ''End" & _
                " FROM tblDropped RIGHT JOIN " & _
                "(tblGraduate RIGHT JOIN " & _
                "(tblDepartment RIGHT JOIN " & _
                "(tblYearLevel RIGHT JOIN " & _
                "(tblSection RIGHT JOIN " & _
                "(tblStudent LEFT JOIN tblEnrolment " & _
                "ON tblStudent.StudentID = tblEnrolment.StudentID) " & _
                "ON tblSection.SectionID = tblEnrolment.SectionOfferingID) " & _
                "ON tblYearLevel.YearLevelID = tblEnrolment.YearLevelID) " & _
                "ON tblDepartment.DepartmentID = tblSection.DepartmentID) " & _
                "ON tblGraduate.StudentID = tblStudent.StudentID) " & _
                "ON tblDropped.StudentID = tblStudent.StudentID" & _
                " " & sFilter & _
                " ORDER BY tblStudent.StudentID DESC , tblYearLevel.YearLevelTitle ASC"
```

Comment: Mother of queries... o_o (sorry, could not resist)

Answer (score 0):

Add a Date Field to your table containing the records and filter by most recent. IF the table already has one include a WHERE clause by date?

If I understand your table correctly the last record is always in the last semester, if you know the semester just do a UNIQUE keyword for the Student_ID